# Changing the Kendo UI upload widget's text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I would like to change the default text of `Select` to something more appropriate for the context. I'm using the Kendo Fluent API built on the `HtmlHelper` class and I didn't find a way to change the text neither in the basic functions nor in the localization.

My code is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
      .Name("FilesToUpload")
)
```

There is a suggestion in this [thread](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/upload/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-select-text-on-the-button.aspx) about a jQuery function to change the text, which works perfectly if I use the javascript API of the Upload widget but doesn't work when I create the widget via `Html.Kendo().Upload`.

And even better with the javascript API there is a:

```
localization: {
    select: 'any text'
}
```

Settings you can use, but this doesn't help me either.

If anyone has faced this problem before and tackled it I would really appreciate his help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have just received an answer on the kendo forums in this [thread](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/upload/changing-the-default-select-text-on-the-button-asp-net-mvc.aspx). And the solution is pretty easy, but the feature was just a little hidden in the fluent interface:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
      .Name("FilesToUpload")
      .Messages( m => m.Select("Select unit bulk upload file"))
)
```

Comment: You can also use UploadSelectedFiles to change the text of the default "Upload files" button.

Answer (score 3):

For AngularJS usages this is an example of using the localization, note the k-localization attribute:

```
<input name="Images" type="file" kendo-upload
        k-multiple="true"
        k-upload="inventoryProductDetail.uploadImage"
        k-success="inventoryProductDetail.uploadedImage"
        k-async="{ saveUrl: '/API/UploadFile/.json', autoUpload: true }"
        k-localization="{ select: 'SELECT ME!' }" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunatly you do have to follow the suggestions [on that post](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/upload/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-select-text-on-the-button.aspx).  Here is how to do it in your situation.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
      .Name("FilesToUpload")
)
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FilesToUpload").closest(".k-upload").find("span").text("my text");
    });
</script>
```

I try not to think that the Kendo controls are going to get me to 100%, because then I would be disappointed.  Instead assume they will get you 90% of where you want to go quickly.  Then use jQuery and some detective work to perfect.

Comment: If you try this out and place a breakpoint in the javascript code, you can see, that even when the document is loaded, the upload widget is not.
So the $("#FilesToUpload").closest(".k-upload").find("span") code will return with empty result. Placing the javascript code at the end of the html document does not help either.

Comment: You must be doing this in a partial view that does not load all the libraries.  Before posting this code I tested it in a project of my own.  So your issue may not actually be with this control directly.  Test this on your _Layout page to make sure, where everything should be loaded, and then move it to where you need it.